# how to read json object values and key to the tree view

Tags: json, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

https://plnkr.co/edit/mokM1ILRY8HbF7BAVa5R?p=preview

how can I achieve the same in angular 2

tried to use * ngFor but not able to achieve the same result.

I have also tried to use pipe in the component and get key values but not able to achieve the results.

please help

below is what so far i tried

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" style="border: none">
  <li *ngFor="let t of acquirer_response ">
    <ul>

      <li *ngFor="let txn of t">

        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let req of txn.request">
          {{req.field}} {{req.length}}{{req.value}}
          <li>
        </ul>



      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  </ul>
```

my component file

```
import { Component ,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AcquirerService} from '../services/acquirer.service'
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Component({

  selector : 'acquirer-message',
  templateUrl: '../templates/acquirer.component.html',
  providers :[AcquirerService]


})

export class AcquirerComponent implements  OnInit{

  acquirer_response;
  keysGetter = Object.keys;
constructor(private _acquirerService : AcquirerService){


}

  ngOnInit(){

    this._acquirerService.getAcquirer()
     .subscribe(resAcquirerData => {

       this.acquirer_response = resAcquirerData.transactions;

       console.log(this.acquirer_response);
      // console.log(this.acquirer_response.transactions);
       });



  }

}


@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

json data

I am very new to front end development,I have JSON file which I want to display in a nice GUI or html.

so far I tried to use bootstrap , angular , datatables looks like i am getting lost so if you can help me out that will be great.

MyJOSN file sample

```
{
    "transactions": [{
        "txn": {
            "request": [{
                "Field": "000",
                "length": "004",
                "value": "0100"
            }, {
                "Field": "005",
                "length": "016",
                "value": "11110010 00111100 "
            }
            ],
            "response": [{
                "Field": "000",
                "length": "004",
                "value": "0110"
            }, {
                "Field": "001",
                "length": "008",
                "value": "00110010"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: no one has answered it :(

Comment: Please add sample respond result of getAcquirer()

Comment: @rdanusha i have added the JSON sample data.pls look into it